# "pragma GCC diagnostic ignored" has no effect if it's defined in PCH?

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma, diagnostics, pch

I have several diagnostic pragmas in a header file.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-braces"
```

When I compiled this header file as PCH, these pragmas seem to have no effects in any other source files.
However if I don't compiled it as PCH, it works correctly.

I'm not sure if this is a GCC bug? or maybe I'm missing something?

PS: I don't want to ignored these warnings by adding compiler options.

Answer (score 2):

See comment 5 here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431

Likely a currently unsupported feature related to when things are lexed.